# Regular expression for double

Tags: regex, double, data-annotations

I'm trying to validate double with regular expressions in data annotations.

I need a regex that validates as it follows:

Pass:

- 1,00
- 0,01
- 0,00
- 123544,23
- 266,00

Always 2 decimals.

Fails:

- ,22
- 0,
- ,00
- 1,0
- 1,2

So far I've got
`^\d+,\d{2}$`

But it fails when the numbers ends in zero. For example, 23,00 fails when it should pass.

Note: I use comma as separator because of my culture.

EDIT: I'm using globalization for jQuery Validate. In the view I have this script.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    Globalize.culture('es-AR');

    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    }

    $.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || (Globalize.parseFloat(value) >= param[0] && Globalize.parseFloat(value) <= param[1]);
    }

});
```

Comment: What you have should work fine. What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using c#. .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: See this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926370/regularexpression-validation-fails-at-modelstate-isvalid-when-input-is-0-00

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that should work as you wish:

```
^\d+[,](\d{2})(?<=\d+)$
```

Comment: It works the same as before. doesn't accept 23,00  :/

Comment: I tried it again with that expression and it worked for number 23,00, too. '"23,00".match(new RegExp(/^\d+[,](\d{2})(?!=\d+)$/)) -> ["23,00", "00"] - match, ok |
"1,00".match(new RegExp(/^\d+[,](\d{2})(?!=\d+)$/)) -> ["1,00", "00"] - match, ok |
"123544,23".match(new RegExp(/^\d+[,](\d{2})(?!=\d+)$/)) -> ["123544,23", "23"] - match, ok |
",00".match(new RegExp(/^\d+[,](\d{2})(?!=\d+)$/)) -> null - no match, ok |
"1".match(new RegExp(/^\d+[,](\d{2})(?!=\d+)$/)) -> null - no match, ok'

Comment: In what language are you trying that?

Comment: In the second place I wrote that code in JavaScript. I tested it by using the Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: There's something that MVC doesn't like. I tried removing client validation and in server it fails too. If I enter 12,01 works, but if I enter 12,00 does not..