# RegularExpression validation fails at ModelState.IsValid when input is 0.00

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-validation

I have a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169118/validation-still-fails-for-regular-expression-that-only-allows-numbers)

I'm using **MVC**. I have added a **regular expression** in my ViewModel to force the users to enter a number with 1 or 2 decimal places. I am thinking there must be an error in my Regex but the same statement is working fine elsewhere.

**If I put in 0.00 as my rate**, when I submit my form, **ModelState.IsValid returns as false**.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(\d+\.\d{1,2})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid rate with 1 or 2 decimal places")]
public double DecimalRate { get; set; }
```

- If I type any invalid input, it behaves as expected, displaying the
  proper error message and not letting me save the page
- If I put valid input (other than 0.00), it saves properly.
- If I remove the Regex completely, 0.00 is seen as valid input and it
  saves properly.

As per a suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791570/modelstate-isvalid-false-why), I have verified that this rate is causing the error by setting a debug at ModelState.IsValid in Visual Studio and checking the errors.

I have a hunch it might have something to do with the attribute being of type **double**?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't realize Rate might be a special keyword. In my code the name is different, I just changed it here for simplicity. I'll edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your property's data type is `double` (not `string`), so it doesn't represent a series of characters. It represents a numerical value. If your input is `0.00`, then it will represent the value `0`, and not match the regex. I suspect you will encounter the same issue for numbers like `3.00` as well.

If you need the user's inputs to be in a specific format, change your field to a `string` and then use `Convert.ToDouble()` when and if you need to convert it to a number.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct about the 3.00 having the same behaviour.
I find it odd that 0.00 was able to save properly as a double when the regex was not present, but that when it gets converted from a string to a double for the regex, the .00 is dropped.

Comment: There is nothing odd about being able to save `0.00` as a `double`. It is simply converted to the value `0`, which is a valid `double`. If that is converted back to a string again in order to apply a regex to it, it will not match the regex `^(\d+\.\d{1,2})$` because its string value wouldn't have a decimal portion.